# Why is k3d Node 'k3d-gitops-playground-server-0'restarting for more than a minute now?

Tags: kubernetes

I a trying to reproduce [gitops playground](https://github.com/cloudogu/gitops-playground/tree/e25b0f9#argo-cd)

After

```
bash <(curl -s \
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cloudogu/gitops-playground/main/scripts/init-cluster.sh) \
  && sleep 2 && docker run --rm -it --pull=always -u $(id -u) \
    -v ~/.k3d/kubeconfig-gitops-playground.yaml:/home/.kube/config \
    --net=host \
    ghcr.io/cloudogu/gitops-playground --yes --argocd --fluxv2
Initializing k3d-cluster 'gitops-playground'
Cluster 'gitops-playground' already exists. Do you want to recreate the cluster?
 [y/N] 
y
```

I got warning

```
WARN[0158] Node 'k3d-gitops-playground-server-0' is restarting for more than a minute now. Possibly it will recover soon (e.g. when it's waiting to join). Consider using a creation timeout to avoid waiting forever in a Restart Loop.
```

let's check cluster

```
k3d cluster list
NAME                SERVERS   AGENTS   LOADBALANCER
first               1/1       0/0      true
gitops-playground   1/1       0/0      false
```

But .kube/conifg is unchanged. I am not having a valid Kubernetes environment to go on.
Why?